# Problem with displaying sql tables in terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, terminal, macos-catalina

[image]

The uploaded image is self explanatory, but still I will highlight what the problem is. With more than 2 columns the table being displayed has missing column values which concerns me. It can be seen in a different view that `company_id` column has values stored. This has been run on default Mac Terminal App on Mac OS Catalina. If you can find a fix, I would appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Comment: I am there us no problen in sql.

Comment: The strings in city are to lobg fir the terninal and so the spaces of the feld wraps to the begin of line

Comment: Try: select concat ('---',company_city,'---') from .....

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried running the query but it turned out to be even worse looking now. The link for the screenshot is https://imgur.com/8B3ddSO. Can you make anything out of this?

Comment: Yes, so you can see that are space after the string. And this spaces wraps to the begin of the line and overrides th e output from id. Try thus: select company-id, company_name, trim (company_city) from ....

Comment: Yes, you are right. That worked for the `company_city` column. But I still face the issue with company_id column. I have run the command you asked me to run. Here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/l0bVk6I